# Jquery UI load in Lightning Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I'm trying to load JQuery and JQuery UI in a Lightning Component.
JQuery is loading fine, but JQuery UI is giving me an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: n[o].hasOwnProperty is not a function"

I loaded the same files in a visualforce page and it worked, so i don't know why it's not working in a lightning component.

**My Code:**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.style + '/jquery-ui.min.css'}" />
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.style + '/jquery-ui.structure.min.css'}" />
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.style + '/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'}" />
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.style + '/normalize.css'}" />    

    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.jquerylib + '/jquery-3.1.0.min.js', $Resource.jquerylib + '/jquery-ui.min.js')}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}"/>

    <a id="test" href="#">Test JQuery</a>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: can you try using jquery  version 2, not sure if jquery v3 is fully compatible with locker service.

Comment: Well but JQuery it's working, the problem is with JQuery UI...

Comment: Ok i tried JQuery2 and it worked, but the problem is that my script now is full of errors, i have to change everything. I love how Lightning Components work, but this problems with external libs is slowly killing my interesse on them.

Comment: What errors do you see? Is it related to jquery-ui.js? if thats' the case then you might need to raise a case with sf support

Comment: Well i had a script with a lot of jqueryUI functions and in visualforce it worked well with latest JQuery and latest JQuery UI. But now, in lightning i have to use Jquery2 so there are many functions not working, and i guess it's pretty normal because that functions probably are from Jquery3.

Comment: ok, shall i post the above comment as answer?. So that we can close the question

Comment: I guess we can do that yes. Althought i would love to see a fix for the JQuery3 issue.

Comment: Ricardo Coutinho,  As far is fix is concerned, you need to raise a case with sf support.So that they can track it and fix it.

Comment: I could do that if i had the time, i will use a visualforce page, i don't have the time to open a ticket and wait for a fix. Thank's anyway, i hope lightning components fix this external libs issue soon so i can have future projects on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jquery v2, i don't think jquery v3 is fully compatible with locker service.

Comment: Seems like Winter'17 didn't help :(